# Unzipping selected files from a zip file

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I have a zip file with internal folder structure as:

```
CODE
`-- CODE
    `-- CODE
        `-- CODE
            |-- 2019
            |   |-- file1.txt
            |   `-- file2.txt
            |-- 2020
            |   `-- file3.txt
            `-- 2021
                |-- file4.txt
                `-- file5.txt
```

And I want to unzip the files in folder structure as given below:

```
CODE
|-- 2019
|   |-- file1.txt
|   `-- file2.txt
|-- 2020
|   `-- file3.txt
`-- 2021
    |-- file4.txt
    `-- file5.txt
```

I could hard code it, however, since it is a repeating request, can I programmatically handle this to unzip only folders which have files in them.

My current code is:

```
def unzipfiles(incoming_path):
    for path,subdirs,files in os.walk(incoming_path):
        for name in files:
            if(name.endswith('.zip')):
                with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(incoming_path,name), 'r') as zip_ref:
                    for file in zip_ref.namelist():
                        out_path=os.path.join(incoming_path,file)
                        out_path=out_path.replace('CODE/','')
                        if(out_path[:-1]!=incoming_path):
                            zip_ref.extract(file,out_path)
```

However, it is not working correctly, and creating more folders than present in zip file.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to unzip a file, and then remove any directory inside it that is only holding another directory?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: May I assume that the directory name is repeating, and / or that the first folder containing data is a year number? In other words, is the naming of the folder `CODE` consistent with the zipfile name, and all other subdirectories?

Comment: Yes. I created a new function which is working for me. I have pasted the code in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I use, is mapping the full path of the files, to a relative shorter name. For the solution I will take the zip structure as provided by the OP.

```
import os
import re
import pathlib
import shutil
import zipfile
from pprint import pprint

if __name__ == '__main__':
    toplevel = os.path.join('files')
    new_structure = dict()

    # Let's just extract everything
    with zipfile.ZipFile('CODE.zip', 'r') as zip_file:

        for zip_info in zip_file.infolist():
            path = pathlib.PurePath(zip_info.filename)

            # This writes the data from the old file to a new file.
            if str(path.parent) in new_structure:
                source = zip_file.open(zip_info)
                target = open(os.path.join(new_structure[str(path.parent)], path.name), "wb")

                with source, target:
                    shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)

            # Create the new folder structure mapping, based on the year name.
            # The matches are based on numbers in this example, but can be specified.
            if re.match('\d+', path.name):  
                new_structure[str(path)] = os.path.join(toplevel, path.name)
                os.makedirs(new_structure[str(path)], exist_ok=True)

    pprint(new_structure)
```

The output (`pprint`), shows the remapping structure:

```
{'CODE\\CODE\\CODE\\CODE\\2019': 'files\\2019',
 'CODE\\CODE\\CODE\\CODE\\2020': 'files\\2020',
 'CODE\\CODE\\CODE\\CODE\\2021': 'files\\2021'}
```

The output is a new folder with the following structure:

```
files
|-- 2019
|   |-- file1.txt
|   `-- file2.txt
|-- 2020
|   `-- file3.txt
`-- 2021
    |-- file4.txt
    `-- file5.txt
```

### Notes

There are two interesting points to make:

1. Regex pattern matching is used to determine the file paths `'\d+'`, which simply accepts a list of numbers, if you want to be more precise you can use `\d{4}` to exactly match four digits.
2. This method only assumes one lower level, in other words, multiple nested files will not be unpacked properly. For this the line `if str(path.parent) in new_structure:` has to be changed to take into account multiple parents path.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

```
def removeEmptyFolders(path, removeRoot=True):
  if not os.path.isdir(path):
    return
  files = os.listdir(path)
  if len(files):
    for f in files:
      fullpath = os.path.join(path, f)
      if os.path.isdir(fullpath):
        removeEmptyFolders(fullpath)
  files = os.listdir(path)
  if len(files) == 0 and removeRoot:
    os.rmdir(path)
```